# .NET registering a DLL through RegAsm without populating Windows event log

Tags: .net, dll, regasm, typelib

Well, i have looked for, but haven't found anything similar to what i wish, and i dont even know if that's possible.

What happens is that, some customers still use windows XP, and this windows version limits the  size of the Windows event log to 512 KB, by default.

So when the log has reached its limit, and my installer tries to regster the .dll, I'm getting an exception saying "The event log is full", becasue each time I try to register the .dll, regasm tries to create 5 new lines of warnings in the event log, saying the registration was succesful.

Obs.: I don't want my installer to clean the event log.

I know we can change it manually and increase the size limit, but still, i'd like to know if there's a way to register the .dll through regasm, without generating any new line in the windows event log. (so i wouldn't have problem with that exception anymore)

I have looked the Regasm parameters and couldn't find any.

Is there any way i can do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Windows version places a limit to the size of the Event Log. 512 KB is just the default value of the (default) "Limit to ..." option.

Just have your customers change this value to a higher one, or tell them to clear their Event log. Something tells me they already have intermittent problems with other applications due to the full event log.

Besides, trying to do something to a user's system without leaving a trace in the Event log can be seen as an attempt to hack the system by some tools and admins ....

Comment: I see..
Didn't know it could be seen as an attempt to hack the system..
Thank you very much.

Comment: Just think, how would you react if you found that an installer tried to bypass the Event log?